# How to get name from id in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

`course` table contains 4 courses.

A single university contains multiple courses, so `university` table contains `course_id`, `values 1,2`.

Can't apply foreign key because of multiple values.

Then how to get the `course_name` from `course` table respectively.

I have already tried `implode` and `explode` method.

In JSON response getting

```
course_id: 1,2
```

I want name of these both(1,2) course name

Pls Help & suggest query.

Comment: _values 1,2..._ Stop! Do not store comma separated data into the db.. think about normalization

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Ya that's possible. But I want to use this method & multi select drop down also gives comma separated (1,2) values. @B001ᛦ

Comment: Use subquery?  ..

Comment: _But I want to use this method.._ You really don't want it.. you think you do so because you don't know the correct approach...re-think your approach...it is fine if _multi select drop down also gives comma separated_